# Retrieveing media liked by the user returns nothing

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get the media liked by the logged in user. I do the authentication process and get an access token like this.

*1312564049.dd97f3a.e9gw8d5516414d348c0b34f328e80fb1*

I made sure to ask for `public_content` scope permission as well.

[image]

Then I call the [`/users/self/media/liked`](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed_liked) endpoint passing this token.

```
let urlString = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked"
let params = ["access_token": token]

Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: params, encoding: .URL, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
    print(response.description)
}
```

But I get the following as the result.

```
{
    data = (
    );
    meta = {
        code = 200;
    };
    pagination = {
    };
}
```

There are many photos liked by the user account I use. So I'm baffled why this returns empty. Is this because I'm in sandbox mode? Or something wrong with this endpoint? Because I checked `/users/self` and `/users/self/media/recent` and they both returned results.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. I think it's related to sandbox mode, as my non sandbox apps are working. But there doesn't seem to be a way to escape sandbox mode.

Comment: To clarify it doesn't seem like they support displaying Liked media anymore, as it's not one of the use cases you can submit for approval to escape sandbox mode.

Comment: @Picard102 That is a shame. I submitted this issue directly to Instagram as well. I'll report back once I receive a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the sanbox mode.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

> Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users

Comment: Yes, but in my case, it doesn't return anything at all. Not even 20 most recent media.